# An error is "Cannot read property 'contact' of null" in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am creating a caller name speaker app in ionic 4. For this, I am able to get incoming caller state and number. With the number, I want to find a name in the contact.

here code:

```
phonecalls() {
PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function (obj) {
  alert("CHANGE STATE: " + obj.state);
  var callObj = JSON.parse(obj),
    state = callObj.state,
    callingNumber = callObj.incomingNumber;
  console.log("obj: " + obj);

  //working
  alert("callingNumber STATE: " + callingNumber);

  //call name get
  const options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = callingNumber;
  options.multiple = true;
  options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
  this.contact.find(['*'], options).then((contacts) => {
    this.contactsfoundcallingNumber = contacts[0].displayName;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[0]));
  });

  alert("well well: " + this.contactsfoundcallingNumber)

  switch (state) {
    case "RINGING":
      console.log("Phone is ringing", callingNumber);
      break;
    case "OFFHOOK":
      console.log("Phone is off-hook");
      break;
    case "IDLE":
      console.log("Phone is idle");
      break;
  }
});
}
```

here chrome inspect using USB debugging

[image]

Comment: show us `component.html`

Comment: nothing in a component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your callback function to an Arrow function, the `this` reference will be preserved.

```
PhoneCallTrap.onCall((obj) => {
    // rest of the code
})
```

Comment: and one more thing, when the app starts and in a 1st incoming call, I am getting the first contact without the find. why this happening any idea?

Comment: @user9088454 So, `find()` is an API call I believe. How can you say that you got the first contact without a `find()`, you see in an Alert? Does this code belong to a service which already has the firstContact in it? It will be nice you can put up another question and add all the relevant details.